# How can I make an std::istream take input from the keyboard (like std::cin)?

Tags: c++, input, console-application

I'm designing a console game where I've come across the issue that I need to have a way that is guaranteed to pause the program. Normally, `std::cin.get()` would be acceptable, but I'm already using `std::cin` for various input tasks, so it's possible that the stream would not be clear, resulting in `cin.get()` to not pause the program.

I thought that, since `std::cin` is just an `std::istream`, I should be able to create a custom `std::istream` that is "untainted" by user input. The problem is, of course, that solution isn't working. Specifically here's the code for the function:

```cpp
inline void pause()
{
    std::stringbuf strm_buf;
    std::istream pause_strm(&strm_buf);
    pause_strm.get();  // I figured this would work since the stream is guarenteed to be empty
}
```

Looking in debug, the `pause_strm.get()` is just returning `-1`.

For reference, I'm using VS2019. I need this pause function because I also have a `cls()` function (uses preprocessor statements to figure out the OS). Please note that I am totally aware that `system("pause")` exists, but it's (in my opinion) not a good solution, and I do not want to use it.

Comment: The assumption that any `std::istream::get()` would block is wrong. The reason behind `std::cin::get()` is blocking is that it's de facto reading from a file so it's waiting for some bytes to be provided from the OS. If you, however, closed the `stdin` (which is the file descriptor of the file that `std::cin` is reading), `std::cin::get()` would also return `EOF`, meaning there is nothing to read.
That being said, you should now understand why your solution isn't working - `get()` is returning -1 (`EOF`), which means there is nothing to read.

Comment: What is wrong with `ignore`?

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign Read my comment on the ProXicT's answer

Comment: @DrakeJohnson `peek` might help you. It returns `eof` if there is nothing to peek at.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign That's a good idea. I'll look into that; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the comment, I described why your solution isn't working as you might have expected.

You said you can't use `std::cin::get()` because you're already using it to get some input, thus the `std::cin` buffer could be non-empty. So maybe just clearing the `std::cin` buffer using something like `std::cin.clear();` would do the trick for you?

Comment: This is possible. In fact, I have a `valid_input()` template function that abstracts away `std::cin` and usually clears the buffer. However, the normal `cin.get()` still may not be reliable 100% of the time. The `istream::clear()` command only resets the error states of an `istream` object. What would clear the stream is `istream::ignore(/* num of chars to ignore */, /* delim char to stop ignoring at */)`. The problem with this is, when the stream is already empty, it just pauses. So I need something that is guarenteed to only pause ONCE, which is the trick.